# How can i make sure that i am on About us page of a particular website

Tags: python, request, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, logic

Here's a snippet of code which i am trying to use to retrieve all the links from a website given the URL of a homepage.

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.udacity.com"
response = requests.get(url)
page = str(BeautifulSoup(response.content))


def getURL(page):

    start_link = page.find("a href")
    if start_link == -1:
        return None, 0
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
    url = page[start_quote + 1: end_quote]
    return url, end_quote

while True:
    url, n = getURL(page)
    page = page[n:]
    if url:
        print url
    else:
        break
```

The result is

```
/uconnect
#
/
/
/
/nanodegree
/courses/all
#
/legal/tos
/nanodegree
/courses/all
/nanodegree
uconnect
/
/course/machine-learning-engineer-nanodegree--nd009
/course/data-analyst-nanodegree--nd002
/course/ios-developer-nanodegree--nd003
/course/full-stack-web-developer-nanodegree--nd004
/course/senior-web-developer-nanodegree--nd802
/course/front-end-web-developer-nanodegree--nd001
/course/tech-entrepreneur-nanodegree--nd007
http://blog.udacity.com
http://support.udacity.com
/courses/all
/veterans
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.udacity.android
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id819700933?mt=8
/us
/press
/jobs
/georgia-tech
/business
/employers
/success
#
/contact
/catalog-api
/legal
http://status.udacity.com
/sitemap/guides
/sitemap
https://twitter.com/udacity
https://www.facebook.com/Udacity
https://plus.google.com/+Udacity/posts
https://www.linkedin.com/company/udacity

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I want to get the URL of only "about us" page of a website which differs in many cases like

for Udacity it is https://www.udacity.com/us

For artscape-inc it is https://www.artscape-inc.com/about-decorative-window-film/

I mean, i could try searching for keywords like "about" in the URLs but as said i might have missed udacity in this approach. Could anyone suggest any good approach?

Comment: It's unlikely there *is* a good approach - websites are free to put their About Me equivalent wherever they want (or nowhere at all) and call it whatever they like.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: yaa, that ok
but still it's about how much more i could decrease the number of false positives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not be easy to cover every possible variation of an "About us" page link, but here is the initial idea that would work in both cases you've shown - check for "about" inside the `href` attribute and the text of `a` elements:

```
def about_links(elm):
    return elm.name == "a" and ("about" in elm["href"].lower() or \
                                "about" in elm.get_text().lower())
```

Usage:

```
soup.find_all(about_links)  # or soup.find(about_links)
```

What you can also do to decrease the number of false positives is to check "footer" part of the page only. E.g. find `footer` element, or an element with `id="footer"` or having a `footer` class.

---

Another idea to sort of "outsource" the "about us" page definition, would be to google (from your script, of course) "about" + "webpage url" and grab the first search result.

---

As a side note, I've noticed you are still using [`BeautifulSoup` version 3](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html) - *it is not being developed and maintained* and you should switch to [`BeautifulSoup` 4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) as soon as possible, install it via:

```
pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
```

And change your import to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```