# No results when scraping About Us reference in websites

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list of urls and I would like to see if there is or is not a section called 'About us' or Contact there.

My approach is as follows ([How can i make sure that i am on About us page of a particular website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816302/how-can-i-make-sure-that-i-am-on-about-us-page-of-a-particular-website)):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = ["https://www.stackoverflow.com", "http://grandeinganno.it", "https://towardsdatascience.com"]

for u in url: 
   response = requests.get(u)
   page = str(BeautifulSoup(response.content))


def getURL(page):

    start_link = page.find("a href")
    if start_link == -1:
        return None, 0
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
    url = page[start_quote + 1: end_quote]
    return url, end_quote

while True:
    url, n = getURL(page)
    page = page[n:]
    if url:
        print (url)
    else:
        break
```

The following code check for "about" inside the `href` attribute and the text of `a` elements:

```
    def about_links(elm):
        return elm.name == "a" and ("about" in elm["href"].lower() or \
                                    "about" in elm.get_text().lower())


    soup.find_all(about_links)
```

Unfortunately, even if I am using the code and suggestion from that question, something is not working as I am not getting any result but error (AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'descendants') when I start to scrape info on 'About us' from websites.

How can I determine where the error is?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Hi AMC, yes, I do it. The problem it seems in the first part, when I try to collect `href` and `a`. An error that I found is the following: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'descendants' when I try to collect info on 'About us' from townrdsdatascience.

Comment: When you get the html from the request, do you see the information that you need in the html? There is a high chance that it's not in it.

Comment: For towardsdatascience I have got as follows: `<a href="https://medium.com/about?autoplay=1&amp;source=collection_home-------------------------------------" class="ec ed by bz ca cb cc cd ce bg pi cf oz pa" rel="noopener">About</a>` , so it seems there are info on this. What I would like to get is just a 'yes' or 'not' (NaN value) in case there is or there is not a section on About Us/Contact us on the web. Also in stackoverflow there is a section 'About' (you can scroll down and see it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will check, if there exists `<a>` tag inside the page that contains "about" or "contact us". If yes, return `True`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


urls = ["https://www.stackoverflow.com", "http://grandeinganno.it", "https://towardsdatascience.com"]

def check(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    # check if there exists <a> tag with "about" or "contact us"
    tag = soup.find(lambda t: t.name=='a' and 'about' in t.text.lower() or 'contact us' in t.text.lower())
    return bool(tag)

for url in urls:
    print('{:<30} {}'.format(url, check(url)))
```

Prints:

```
https://www.stackoverflow.com  True
http://grandeinganno.it        False
https://towardsdatascience.com True
```